# why not working function javascript resize?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, resize, width

My code javascript not working.
I want the functions work if will be over 500px width screen.

```
<ul>
  <li class="dawid">Dawid</li>
  <li class="piotrek">Piotr</li>
  <li class="to">Tomek</li>
</ul>
```

AND JAVASCRIPT CODE- NOT WORKING

```
document.getElementById("dawid").addEventListener("click",displaytwo);
document.getElementById("piotrek").addEventListener("click",displayone);



function displaytwo(){

                    document.getElementById("piotrek").style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById("tomek").style.display='none';
                                }

function displayone(){
                    document.getElementById("dawid").style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById("tomek").style.display='none';
          }
```

RESIZE NOT WORKING

```
function screen_resize(){
var w = parseInt(window.innerWidth);
   if(w > 500)
   { 

     displaytwo();
     displayone();
   }}
$(window).resize(function(e) {
screen_resize();
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    screen_resize();
});
```

Comment: dont work, after change

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `.getElementById` you need ids on your elements:

```
<ul>
  <li class="da" id="dawid">Dawid</li>
  <li class="pi" id="piotrek">Piotr</li>
  <li class="to" id="piotrek">tomek</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare IDs on your HTML elements, or else getElementByID() will not work.

```
<ul>
    <li id="dawid" class="da">Dawid</li>
    <li id="piotr" class="pi">Piotr</li>
    <li id="tomek" class="to">Tomek</li>
</ul>
```

It looks like you are also using jQuery and already assigned them classes, so you could also use this code to grab DOM elements by class:

```
$(".da").click(displaytwo);
$(".pi").click(displayone);

function displaytwo(){
    $(".piotrek").css('display','none');
    $(".tomek").css('display','none');
}

function displayone(){
    $(".dawid").css('display','none');
    $(".tomek").css('display','none');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ids are missing in your elements `li`, add the IDs:

```
<li class="dawid" id="dawid">Dawid</li>
<li class="piotrek" id="piotrek">Piotr</li>
<li class="to" id="tomek">Tomek</li>
```

```js
document.getElementById("dawid").addEventListener("click", displaytwo);
document.getElementById("piotrek").addEventListener("click", displayone);

function displaytwo() {
  document.getElementById("piotrek").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("tomek").style.display = 'none';
}

function displayone() {
  document.getElementById("dawid").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("tomek").style.display = 'none';
}


function screen_resize() {
  var w = parseInt(window.innerWidth);
  if (w > 500) {
    displaytwo();
    displayone();
  }
}

$(window).resize(function(e) {
  screen_resize();
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
  screen_resize();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dawid" id="dawid">Dawid</li>
  <li class="piotrek" id="piotrek">Piotr</li>
  <li class="to" id="tomek">Tomek</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: here everything disappears,
I would like the functions to work after exceeding the resolution. And when you click on one, the rest disappears